# Calculate ratio for subsets within subsets using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of data for many authors (AU), spanning multiple years (Year) and multiple topics (Topic). For each AU, Year, and Topic combination I want to calculate a ratio of the total FL by Topic / total FL for the year.

The data will look like this:

```
Data <- data.frame("AU" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
               "Year" = c(2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2010,2010,2010,2011,2011,2011,2011,2010,2011,2011),
               "Topic" = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
               "FL" = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1))
```

I've been playing around with dplyr trying to figure out how to do this. I can group_by easy enough but I'm not sure how to go about calculating the ratio using a "group" for numerator and a total across all groups for the denominator

```
Results <- Data %>%
  group_by(Year, AU) %>%
  summarise(ratio = ???) # Should be (Sum(FL) by Topic) / (Sum(FL) across all Topics)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your desired output, you can calculate the total by Topic, Year, AU and total by Year, AU separately and join them together using `left_join`.

```
left_join(
  Data %>% 
    group_by(AU, Year, Topic) %>% 
    summarise(FL_topic = sum(FL)) %>% 
    ungroup(),
  Data %>% 
    group_by(AU, Year) %>% 
    summarise(FL_total = sum(FL)) %>% 
    ungroup(),
  by = c("AU", "Year")
) %>% 
  mutate(ratio = FL_topic/FL_total)

# A tibble: 7 x 6
#      AU  Year Topic FL_topic FL_total ratio
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  2010     1        2        4  0.5 
# 2     1  2010     2        2        4  0.5 
# 3     1  2011     1        0        2  0   
# 4     1  2011     2        2        2  1   
# 5     2  2010     1        1        4  0.25
# 6     2  2010     2        3        4  0.75
# 7     2  2011     1        4        4  1
```